# How to run gui application from web app?

Tags: webapps

I have to run a grafic application on ubuntu 12.04 LTS from my Web App. All works greate, but every time I boot the pc, I must run "xhost +" comand on terminal to execute the application.

If I run the application from terminal, all starts, but from the Web App no.
Is there a solution to avoid to tipe this comand everty time?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replay! I have found the solution. If someone could be interested, this is my solution:
My problem was that at every reboot I had to run the `xhost +` comand.
So I created a script with this line and I put it in the Startup Applications.
Now works:)

Bye

Answer (score 0):

You can install "Unity desktop" to enabled GUI

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

If you are looking for light weighted GUI, possibly you can try "Gnome" GUI, which can be installed using the below command,

```
sudo apt-get install xorg gnome-core gnome-system-tools gnome-app-install
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried both solution. Ubuntu-desktop was just installed. The second, I have installed but nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try edit the below configuration file with some text editor,

```
/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf
```

and make sure below attribute is set to 2

```
DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2
```

Save the file and do a restart.

Now check system is showing with GUI,